# Calling multiple elements inside an array all at once?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my situation I have for practice. Right now, I'm simply on the very beginnings of Javascript. I'm practicing this inside my console and there's a wall I've hit that I need to figure out.

What I'm trying to do is just simple CSS style changes inside my console on chrome. Here's what I have so far

```
var get = document.getElementById('ul-li-menu');
```

I then get the whole list of li's uls and anchors for my vertical menu inside that variable I called.

I access the anchor tags I want via this code down below.

```
var li = get.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Now I have a whole array of stuff I know I simply have to call the variable in the console like this.

```
li
```

Here's what I'm confused on. I want to, just for the sake of practice, change the display of all these anchor tags.

Here's the code I wrote at first.

```
li.style.display = "inline";
```

but that doesn't work.

I don't want to access each and every individual element inside this array with bracket notation like this [0] or [3].

There are about thirteen of these anchor elements inside this array that I want to access all at once to change the display to inline. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Unlike using jQuery you need to loop through each item and apply the style on them directly `li.forEach(item => { item.style.display = "inline"; })`.

Answer (score 2):

Just go through the for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
    li[i].style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery you need to loop through each object inside the array

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use JQuery for faster approach:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  if($("li").css("display") == "table"){
    $("li").css("display","inline-block");
  }
  else{
    $("li").css("display","table");
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li>0</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
<button type="button">Change Style</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through them and set each one individually. If you're using jQuery or es6 you can do this in a little bit cleaner of a way, but here is how you would do it with just plain ol' javascript.

```
var listItems = document.getElementById('theUlElement').getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var li = 0; li < listItems.length; li ++){
  listItems[li].style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom CSS style rule dynamically using Javascript on your no. of Anchor tags..

### // syntax

// stylesheet.addRule( rule , index );

Answer (score 0):

Another useful option for performing the same action on each element of an array is [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Unfortunately, your variable `li` isn't an array, it's a `NodeList`, which [has limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) for `forEach`.

That said, you can actually just use the array version of `forEach` on your NodeList without any trouble! This will work on IE9+:

```js
[].forEach.call(li, function(item) {
    item.style.display = 'inline';
});
// Array.prototype.forEach.call(...) would also work.
```

If you didn't care about browser support, you could use the NodeList native `forEach`:

```js
li.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.display = 'inline';
});
```